# when reach the 4th slide, restart the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider, ytplayer

I'm using [Flexslider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) and in the 4th slide, I have a youtube video that used [YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer)

here's the html structure of the 4th slide

```
<li>
    <div class="player" data-video-id="ASDsad65w9e52" data-start-at="0>
    </div>
</li>
```

and the javascript on detecting when it reach the 4th slide, I simply used 'end' parameter

```
$('#home-slider').flexslider({
    end : function(){

    }
});
```

and then when it reached the 4th slide or simply the end slide then re-initialized the YTPlayer to play the video on the start or simply play again.

```
$('#home-slider').flexslider({
    end : function(){
        $("#home-slider .player").YTPlayer();
    }
});
```

But unfortunately, its not working, instead it gives me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].YTPPlay is not a function
>       at Object.end (scripts2.js:310)
>       at m.fn.init.a.flexAnimate (flexslider.min.js:1)
>       at a.animateSlides (flexslider.min.js:1)

Any ideas, help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#home-slider .player").YTPPlay();
```

For more reference look up

https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki

move the following code to `$(window).load()`

```
if ($('.player').length) {
    $('section').closest('body').find(".player").YTPlayer();
}

$('.slider-all-controls').flexslider({
    end: function() {
        $('#home-slider .player').YTPlayer();
    }
});
```

note your ytp looks like older version, it does not support `YTPPlay()` it uses `playYTP()`;

though you will need to refactor you code in the site..its way too scrambled

Comment: I got thie error "$(...).YTPPlay is not a function" any ideas?

Comment: @CodeDemon check whether jquery is returning you right object or not.

Comment: how to check whether jquery is returning you right object or not?

Comment: just `console.log($("#home-slider .player"))` and you will get the jquery object, it has properties from which you can figure out whether its right obj or not, in your case it might be an empty array

Comment: try this, 
`$("#home-slider .player")[0].YTPPlay();`

Comment: still it returns $(...)[0].YTPPlay is not a function

Comment: is your player working by default ? and can you post more of your code here ?

Comment: You can check the live site here. http://axada.co.uk/wp/ in the home page slide, navigate to the last slide which contains the video which im pointing in my post here.

Comment: and here's the script that contains the script I'm referring above http://axada.co.uk/wp/wp-content/themes/Axada/js/scripts2.js line 308

Comment: It shows no more errors but seem's its not working like when I navigate to last slide/4th slide, the video does not start again. Any ideas?

Comment: but i have only one initialize flexslider on the current page?